# Revive 1/2 dead HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I have an old 40GB HDD I got from someone. It appears to me as though it is half dead, but not completely.

When I plug it in and power it up, it seems OK. When I try to access it, it just keeps making clicking noises. However, it shows up correctly as being a 40GB volume.

I have no idea if there is any data on it, **nor do I care to recover any data from it. I was going to format it anyway.**

So my question is: Is there any way to revive this HDD, or is it dead?

I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4.

Comment: Which OS are you trying to load it from? If Windows, try with a linux live CD of some sort. If you still can't access it then recovery becomes more expensive. Depends how important the data is to you

Comment: @EricF - Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: Have you tried formatting it somehow?

Comment: Then nope not feasibly if you don't care that much. Just try to format and scan to see if there are bad sectors / failures

Comment: I tried formatting, but it said that the disk took too long to respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because the drive spins up and the computer sees it as a valid drive does not necessarily mean it is still alive, or even usable.

What you are describing sounds like [The Click of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death). Just because the electronics and firmware on the device are functioning properly, does not mean that the hardware is;

From your comment *I tried formatting, but it said that the disk took too long to respond* - what is most likely happening is that the head is attempting to read / write to the platter, but can not tract to the desired location correctly - this result in a head recalibration, where the head is sent back to its home position, where it again tries to reseek the disk, again unsuccessfully.

Being a 40GB HDD, I would say toss it. If you are looking for 40GB, you can find quality ones on Amazon for <$20.

In my eyes, it is absolutely not worth it to store data on a questionable disk.

Comment: Any 40 Gb disk is likely to be well past its expected life (typically about 5 years) in any case. And compared to the price of a 32Gb or 64Gb USB stick, "20 dollars" isn't much of a bargain.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd wanted to recover some data, I'd have suggested giving it a little tap on the side as it is trying to spin up. Otherwise, your friendly neighborhood scrap dealer will give you a smile for the half pound of metal, and that's about all the use you'll get from your disk . . .